# Генерация динамического контента на странице

Tags: javascript, framework

Добрый день.

**Задача:** нужно сделать динамическое наполнение заранее подготовленной страницы. Допустим, я хочу сделать описание всех аэропортов мира и я для этого сверстал шаблон страницы. Но я не хочу ручками заполнять каждую страницу, а хочу, чтобы система сама определяла, информацию о каком аэропорте запрашивает пользователь и в соответствии с его запросом наполняла страницу нужным пользователю контентом. Допустим, у меня есть кнопка на главной странице `<a href="#" data-airport="Sheremetyevo">Шереметьево</a>` и есть страница `example.com/airport`. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на эту кнопку JS брал значение атрибута `data-airport` и:

1. Отправлял пользователя на страницу example.com/airport?=Sheremetyevo
2. Отправлял на эту страницу значение атрибута data-airport таким
   образом, чтобы я в последующем мог к нему обращаться. Ну или вывести
   куда-нибудь его.
   **Вопрос:** какой фреймворк для этого нужно использовать? Смотрю в сторону BackBone.

Comment: Вероятно, любой...

Comment: @Qwertiy подскажите тогда, пожалуйста, как мне правильно гуглить нужную мне информацию? Например, в том же самом BackBone. Я, что называется, смотрю в книгу - вижу фигу.

Comment: Не знаю. Я вообще пока проблемы не увидел, которую бы надо было гуглить...

Comment: В каком формате у вас приходят данные после отправки данных на example.com/airport?=Sheremetyevo ?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не `SPA`, тогда вопрос про выбор серверного фреймворка (`Yii`, `Laravel` - для php, например), если же вы хотите делать `SPA`, тогда стоит посмотреть что-нибудь более *современное*

1. [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)
2. [Anglar](https://angularjs.org/)

Есть и другие: preact, vue и т.д.

После выбора фреймоврка прочитайте про роутинг, для начала вам хватит